# Firefox Annotator SDK tutorial, cannot get the annotator button to work

Tags: firefox, sdk, widget

[Link to the tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Annotator)

I am trying to get to grips with Firefox SDK development using the tutorials on MDN. The annotator tutorials seem very good but CFX Run fails on the first control stage.

The tutorial uses the widget API that was deprecated in Firefox 29 but I tried downgrading Firefox 28 and the tutorial still doesn't work even when I am copy and pasting the code directly from the page code. When I come to the end of the [Implementing the widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Annotator/Implementing_the_widget) page I only get the following message when trying to click the widget icon (the first time, then nothing hapens).

```
(C:\Users\myname\Firefoxplayground\addon-sdk-1.16) C:\Users\myname\Firefoxplay
ground\pageMod>cfx run
Using binary at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'.
Using profile at 'c:\users\sigvard\appdata\local\temp\tmpg3kq0j.mozrunner'.
console.error: pagemod:
  Error opening input stream (invalid filename?)
JavaScript strict warning: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 666
: reference to undefined property this._value
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 648: aUrl is
  undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a bug in the Firefox SDK.

Updating to Firefox SDK 1.16 and initializing a new folder for the project solved it.